# Network path not found for server in Node.js command prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-prompt

Is it possible to change directory to a server with a UNC path in Node.js command prompt? I can access the server just fine through file explorer. I'm using my laptop which is connected to the domain (not logged in to the server itself). The server I'm trying to reach is \\server-1. I have tried running Node.js command prompt in Administrator mode, when I try

```
pushd \\server-1
```

it says "The network path was not found."
I have also tried

```
net use U: \\server-1
```

And it says "System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found."